# WCF - Serialization Exception due to Circular reference

Tags: wcf

I am using DataContract with  preserveObjectReferences set to false (default). Under any circumsatnces will it cause a Circular reference and cause Serialization Exception?

if yes, could you please xplain with a sample scenario?

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely, if you turn the flag off, this simple scenario would result in a serialization exception:

```
public static class X
{
   public static A GlobA;
   public static B GlobB;

   static 
   {
     GlobA = new A();
     GlobB = new B();
     GlobA.someB = GlobB;
     GlobB.someA = GlobA;
   }
}

[DataContract]
public class A
{
    [DataMember]
    public B someB = X.GlobA;
}

[DataContract]
public class B
{
    [DataMember]
    public A someA;
}
```

Now try to serialize an instance of A...